# Splitting an image into two parts (background / foreground) with logical indexing in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, bitmask

I have a problem I don't know how to resolve in Matlab.
Basically. I have an image array hw x 3 and a seperate binary array that defines the background foreground. What I want to do, is split the image into two parts - corresponding to the mask.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What do you mean "split the image"? Which sizes do you want for the two split images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mask is the same for all thre channels, thus simply copy it.

```
I=... %image
M=... %mask
M3=cat(3,M,M,M);
F=zeros(size(I));
B=zeros(size(I));
F(M3)=I(M3);
B(~M3)=I(~M3);
```

Maybe foreground and background is switch, but I think you will get it.

A bit shorter, using multiplication instead of logical indexing:

```
I=... %image
M=... %mask
M3=cat(3,M,M,M);
F=M3.*I;
F=~M3.*I;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit unclear what you mean by "split".
If you mean you want an image with only the foreground - and the background blacked out (set to `[0 0 0]` then

```
fg = bsxfun(@times, img, msk ); % where msk = 1 for FG
bg = bsxfun(@times, img, ~msk );
figure;
subplot(121);imshow( fg ); title('Foreground');
subplot(122);imshow( bg ); title('Background');
```

However, if by "split" you mean you want two arrays of colors `|FG|x3` and `|BG|x3` for foreground and background colors respectively then

```
fg = reshape(img,[],3); % all pixels stacked
bg = fg( ~msk, : ); % take the background 30vectors
fg = fg( msk, : );
```